# regex to capture first numeric group

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a series of str values within a dataframe:

```
S10|1828575
S10|1828575
S10|1828575
S10|1828575
SA510KPBF|47010705
SA510KPBF|47010705
SABLF|47009610
SABLF|47009610
SABLF|47009610
```

I want to capture all numeric values before `|`

Expected:

```
10
10
10
10
510
510
```

Using:

```
\d.+?(?=\|)
```

After many attempts Ive managed to get this far.. What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
\d+(?=.*\|)
```

The only change is to add `.*` in your lookahead before the pipe to look ahead for anything followed by a pipe.

---

To utilize this in your `dataframe` to create a new column with the numbers only, we can use `extract()`.

To do this, we will need to put our above `regex` in a capturing group by enclosing the pattern between `()`.

```
r'(\d+(?=.*\|))'
```

---

Code

```
d = ['S10|1828575',
'S10|1828575',
'S10|1828575',
'S10|1828575',
'SA510KPBF|47010705',
'SA510KPBF|47010705',
'SABLF|47009610',
'SABLF|47009610',
'SABLF|47009610']

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['numbers'] = df[0].str.extract(r'(\d+(?=.*\|))')
```

Output

```
>>> df
                    0 numbers
0         S10|1828575      10
1         S10|1828575      10
2         S10|1828575      10
3         S10|1828575      10
4  SA510KPBF|47010705     510
5  SA510KPBF|47010705     510
6      SABLF|47009610     NaN
7      SABLF|47009610     NaN
8      SABLF|47009610     NaN
```

Comment: The OP is using Python, so your answer should probably have some Python code in it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I understand. All the OP needs to do is replace his `re(pattern)` with the one I have added. The issue is not directed towards an issue with `re` so I didn't include that part.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Updated to include relevant Pyhon code for `pandas`

Answer (score 1):

A bit more efficient pattern could be matching non digits from the start of the string.

Then capture the first digits in group 1 *(which will be used for the new column)* and match until the first encounter of a pipe `|` instead of using a lookahead.

```
\A\D*(\d+)[^|]*\|
```

- `\A` Start of string
- `\D*` Match optional non digits
- `(\d+)` Capture group 1, match 1+ digits
- `[^|]*\|` Match any char other than a `|` followed by matching the `|`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RoHS8L/1)

Example code

```
import pandas as pd

strings = ['S10|1828575',
     'S10|1828575',
     'S10|1828575',
     'S10|1828575',
     'SA510KPBF|47010705',
     'SA510KPBF|47010705',
     'SABLF|47009610',
     'SABLF|47009610',
     'SABLF|47009610']

df = pd.DataFrame(strings, columns=["str_values"])
df['first_numeric'] = df["str_values"].str.extract(r'\A\D*(\d+)[^|]*\|')
print(df)
```

Output

```
           str_values first_numeric
0         S10|1828575            10
1         S10|1828575            10
2         S10|1828575            10
3         S10|1828575            10
4  SA510KPBF|47010705           510
5  SA510KPBF|47010705           510
6      SABLF|47009610           NaN
7      SABLF|47009610           NaN
8      SABLF|47009610           NaN
```